# Project won't level resources

Tags: microsoft-project

I'm using Project 2013 and have a rather large project file I'm working with and at some point it stopped level resources.  I have roughly 1100 or so tasks, they are grouped into roughly 6 task groups.  Think of it like Step1->Step2->...Step6.  The tasks have dependencies between them in each group, but the groups themselves are independent of each other.  I handle the scheduling by using priority values.

At one point this worked well, but after someone wanted me to change resource availability to say 50% from 100%, things went strange.  I'm not sure this was a direct cause, just a coincidence.

At this point, if I find an overallocation, when I right click and request it to be rescheduled to the next available time, nothing happens.  When I choose to clear leveling and re-level all resources, nothing happens.  Previously this would take roughly 30 seconds or so, now it immediately finishes with no information and no changes.

I'm wondering if it could be a corrupt file, or something else.  I tried saving in a 2007 format an that didn't fix anything.

Comment: I noticed in the Team Planner view it has just stacked all sorts of tasks on top of each other.... Pretty useless.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it might be better suited to the PM SE site here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found that when that happens, if I go into the resource's property window and select "Change Working Time...", simply click ok and ok again. I am now able to level the resource. may be a corrupt file, but this is a workaround.